# Version of @angular/compiler-cli needs to be 2.3.1 or greater. Current version is "7.0.1"

Tags: angular, angular-material

I cannot run my project with angular material using ng serve. It gives me this error:

"Version of @angular/compiler-cli needs to be 2.3.1 or greater. Current version is "7.0.1"."

This is in what I have in my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/http": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/material": "^7.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "^7.0.1",
    "animate.css": "^3.5.2",
    "arrive": "^2.3.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.5",
    "bootstrap-notify": "^3.1.3",
    "bootstrap-select": "^1.12.2",
    "bootstrap-tagsinput": "^0.7.1",
    "chartist": "^0.9.4",
    "chartist-plugin-zoom": "^0.4.0",
    "chartjs-plugin-zoom": "^0.5.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "datatables": "1.10.12",
    "datatables.net-bs": "1.10.12",
    "datatables.net-responsive": "^2.1.1",
    "domready": "^1.0.8",
    "eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "4.17.47",
    "fullcalendar": "^3.4.0",
    "googleapis": "^19.0.0",
    "jasny-bootstrap": "^3.1.3",
    "jquery": "^1.12.4",
    "nouislider": "^9.2.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "twitter-bootstrap-wizard": "^1.2.0",
    "validate": "^3.0.1",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.2.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.0.1",
    "@types/bootstrap": "^3.3.32",
    "@types/chartist": "^0.9.34",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/jquery": "^1.10.31",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.73",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "^3.1.3"
  }
```

Can you please help me how to resolve this? Thank you

Comment: did you try with prune? npm prune ... npm install

Answer (score 0):

This issue is because your angular-cli version in package is 1.0.0 , you need to update it to recente version. For ex,

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "7.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "7.0.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "7.0.1",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "1.1.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.9",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.5",
    "@types/node": "8.10.30",
    "codelyzer": "4.5.0",
    "husky": "1.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "3.3.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "karma": "3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "2.0.4",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.4.0",
    "lint-staged": "7.3.0",
    "ng-packagr": "4.4.0",
    "prettier": "1.14.3",
    "protractor": "5.4.1",
    "stylelint": "9.6.0",
    "stylelint-order": "1.0.0",
    "stylelint-scss": "3.3.2",
    "ts-node": "7.0.1",
    "tsickle": "0.33.1",
    "tslib": "1.9.3",
    "tslint": "5.11.0",
    "typescript": "3.1.3"
  }
```

Comment: When I change the @angular/cli to 7.0.3 I get the error about ng serve must be ran in angular project

Comment: can you paste the errorr, also did you do npm install after chaning?

Comment: Yes I did the npm install Sir. I deleted the project so I can't replicate the exact error message. But it has something to do with ng serve and the angular.json is not defined